# Google Forms Dynamic multiple choice with pictures

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a dynamic multiple choice google form that is working fine except for if i add a picture to the option box using the attach picture function in the google form editing screen.
When the form refreshes all the pictures are lost.
below is the code for the dynamic form.

What i need is to be able to assign a picture the the option title.

```
function updateLists() {
var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B-yHzwrw6kldVDVzZlA5bTlScDg").getFiles()
while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   var form = FormApp.openById(file.getId())
   var items = form.getItems();
   for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i += 1){
    var item = items[i]
    if (item.getTitle() === "Requested Award"){
     var agentList = item.asMultipleChoiceItem()
     }
    }
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Menu");
  var agentValues = ss.getRange(1, 15, ss.getMaxRows() - 1).getValues();
  var agentNames = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < agentValues.length; i++)    
    if(agentValues[i][0] != "")
    agentNames[i] = agentValues[i][0];
    agentList.setChoiceValues(agentNames);
}
}
```